# Access Query. If records Due Date = Last Week Insert Yes in Cell

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Good morning All,

I am working on the following however, I can't figure it out for the life of me. I have table that contains a bunch of due dates. What I am trying to do is add a query that adds another field and inserts a yes if the date equals a day in last week. Honestly I need it to insert yes as long as it does not = this week.

I've tried using:

```
Urgent: IIf([Due Date]=[Due Date] 
Between 
DateAdd("d",1-Weekday(Date()) 7, Date()) And 
DateAdd("d",1-Weekday(Date())-1, Date()),"Yes","")
```

with no luck. What am I missing here?!

Thanks all. Cheers.

Comment: If I remove the [Due Date] = [Due Date] I get an error. I can't use [Due Date] Between. It errors out.

Comment: It was my fault. I forgot a parenthesis however, when I use:

    IIf([Due Date] Between DateAdd("d",1-Weekday(Date())-7,Date()) And DateAdd("d",1-Weekday(Date())-1,Date()),"Yes","")

If I put in 09/18/2015 which is last friday the cell stays blank, it does not show up "Yes". Sorry for all the trouble. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I never stated that the problem is a syntax error. I just happened to try what you provided and got an error due to my mistake. The problem is still the same. I am using the above and it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: how about comparing `datepart("ww",[Due Date])` and `datepart("ww",now())` ?  see http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datepart.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to return Urgent if 'not this week' means previous Saturday and before. Not sure how you would do it without code.

Helper Function to get the first day of this week based on current date. Paste it into a new or existing global module.

```
Function FirstDateOfTheWeek() As Date
  Dim dt As Date

  If Weekday(Date) = vbSaturday Then
    FirstDateOfTheWeek = DateAdd("y", -6, Date) 'today is Saturday? then return previous Sunday
  ElseIf Weekday(Date) = vbSunday Then
    FirstDateOfTheWeek = Date 'today is Sunday? then return Sunday because its the first day of the week
  Else 'weekday, so just go backwards until we hit previous sunday's date
    dt = Date
    While Weekday(dt) <> vbSunday
      dt = DateAdd("y", -1, dt)
    Wend
    FirstDateOfTheWeek = dt
  End If

End Function
```

An IsUrgent function to be called from query. Paste it into a new or existing global module.

```
Function IsUrgent(dt As Variant) As String

  If IsNull(dt) Then 'if null date is passed then return blank string; Variant chosen instead of date for this case; change it to N/A if you want?
    IsUrgent = ""
    Exit Function
  End If

  If dt < FirstDateOfTheWeek Then
    IsUrgent = "Yes"
  Else
    IsUrgent = ""
  End If

End Function
```

The Query Column calling IsUrgent() function:

```
IsUrgent: IsUrgent([Due Date])
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! If I try this. I get "Yes" even if I put in 09/21/2015. Basically I need it to say yes when the due date does not equal this week.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, I can't imagine why it doesn't work for you. It's a pretty straight forward date calculation. Could it be that you've been changing your system date while testing?

Comment: I have not. Yes, it is pretty strange indeed since for whatever reason it does not want to update correctly.

Comment: @William: Is [Due Date] a date in a table or is it a calculated field in a query? Also, are you trying to update [Urgent] as a col in a table or are you just displaying it in a query?

Comment: [Due Date] is a date in my table. I am trying to display [Urgent] in the query.

Comment: Thanks! Please see if my new edited answer works for you.

Comment: You sir are a genius. Thank you so much for this!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I really really appreciate it.!

Comment: You are so welcome @William, glad we could help! Sorry to all for the 'extended discussion'. I'm still pretty new to this site and promise to do a better job in the future. Have a nice day.

Comment: you as well. Again thank you so much for this. Tested it all day and it works like a charm.